# Unique message ID in SMTP module

Tags: 7, emails

I am working with Drupal 7. In my site am using the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module to send emails. After sending an email, I want to get the unique encrypted message ID string. Now I am getting the message ID as:

Example:

1. `user_registrationpassword_register` for registration
2. `user_password_reset` for reset password.

How can I get the unique encrypted string for each email sending from the site?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique encrypted message ID string"? What's wrong with `user_registrationpassword_register`?

Comment: Actually i need a string like "9XAq2GUEgFSWApTlSNqkmFRnb63jAiaIpCCbOyZbfQ" as message id.Iam going to use O365 API for finding some data related to each mail.In order to get this data,need to pass a unique message id to the API.